# Problems recycling c++ lib with templated class for Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, library

I have a header & cpp file located in Arduino\libraries\Parentfolder\Header&Cpp. Arduino IDE recognizes my lib (the class is color coded & Sketch->include library->MyLibrary shows in the dropdown menu and #includes properly).

Problem: Arduino IDE gives `undefined reference to MyClass . . .` error in my sketch for every reference of the class including function calls. The function fully in other IDEs as header/cpps so I don't think pasting the cody is necessary -- what could I be missing? I've read a million Stack Exchange posts with similar error/watched a million YouTube guides on writing Arduino libs and I can't seem to find the differentiating factors that would make my code *not* work for Arduino IDE.

tl;dr what are the reasons that a working c++ library (self-made) would not work with Arduino IDE?

/e

```
Queue.h
#ifndef Queue_h
#define Queue_h

#include "Arduino.h"

template <typename T>
class Queue
{
  public:
    typedef struct node
    {
      T data;
      node * next = nullptr;
    } * nodePtr;

    nodePtr head; // = nullptr;
    nodePtr tail; // = nullptr;
    nodePtr curr; // = nullptr;
    nodePtr temp; // = nullptr;

    unsigned int counter;

    Queue();
    void push(T);
    T& peek();
    T pop();
    int size();
    bool isEmpty();
    void clear();
};

#endif
```

Queue.cpp

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "Queue.h"

template <typename T>
Queue<T>::Queue()
{
    nodePtr head = nullptr;
    nodePtr tail = nullptr;
    nodePtr curr = nullptr;
    nodePtr temp = nullptr;

    counter = 0;
}

template <typename T>
void Queue<T>::push(T data)
{
  if (head == nullptr)
  {
    head = new node;
    head->data = data;
    tail = head;
  }
  else
  {
    temp = head;
    head = new node;
    head->data = data;
    head->next = temp;    
  }
  counter ++;
}

template <typename T>
T& Queue<T>::peek()
{
  if (head == nullptr)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  return head->data;

}

template <typename T>
T Queue<T>::pop()
{
  // Empty
  if (head == nullptr)
  {
    return 0;
  }

  // Head = tail
  if (head == tail)
  {
    T data = head->data;
    delete head;
    return data;
  }

  // Size > 1
  curr = head;
  while (curr->next != tail)
  {
    curr = curr->next;
  }
  T data = curr->next->data;  
  tail = curr;
  curr = curr->next;
  delete curr;
  counter --;
  return data;
}

template <typename T>
int Queue<T>::size()
{
  return counter;
}

template <typename T>
bool Queue<T>::isEmpty()
{
  if (counter ==0)
  {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

template <typename T>
void Queue<T>::clear()
{
  while (head->data != nullptr)
  {
    temp = head->next;
    delete head;
    head = temp;    
  }
  if (head == nullptr)
  {
    return;
  }
  delete head;
  return;
}
```

.ino

```
. . .
Queue<float> avgQueue;
. . .
```

error

```
. . . In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
. . . undefined reference to `Queue<float>::Queue()'
```

***SOLVED:***

Combining the .cpp contents in the .h and removing the .cpp worked.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Do you have a single sketch file, or have you broken your code into multiple files (eg. cpp/h files)?

Comment: The header and cpp are in the forementioned subfolder which is inside of the Arduino library folder. The errors come from a simple sketch meant only to test the (already-working-in-other-IDEs) library.

Comment: one thing that jumps out is the ampersand `&` in the path ... maybe the compiler does not like it

Comment: That's not the real path, that's just me saying that both the header&cpp are there.

Answer (score -1):

***SOLVED:***

Putting the .cpp contents in the .h and removing the .cpp from the lib folder entirely worked.

Comment: Yes, tempates are instantiated on demand so you have to have complete class inside of header. However I wonder how the `pop` works if you have the last element. Your `head` wasn't set to the nullptr - and `delete` can't do that for you.

Comment: Your code doesn't totally prove the problem, however libraries are not included unless you include them in the .ino file which might be your underlying issue.

Comment: This, for example, is not **complete** code: `. . .
Queue<float> avgQueue;
. . .`

Comment: @NickGammon fortunately I'm not that much of a noob! The lib was included and everything is now functioning well as a result of the above workaround

Comment: I'm glad it is working, however I'm not sure what you did exactly (that didn't work) and what you did (that did work). However [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612791/c-template-and-header-files) looks relevant.